# How to prove this statement from Geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{i}$, this converges to $S = \frac{1}{1-r}$, show that $S - s_n = \frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}$, where $s_n$ is the sum of first n terms.

My approach,

$S - s_n = \frac{1}{1-r} - \frac{1-r^n}{1-r} = \frac{r^n}{1-r}$

So, there's no $r^{n+1}$ in my answer like it is in the question. If we have $s_n$, it means the sum of first $n$ terms, so there shouldn't be any $n+1$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: $S-s_n=\frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ seems to be wrong as checking by putting $n=0$.

Comment: Maybe your $s_n$ means the sum to the term $r^n$.

Comment: Typo.:  in $\sum$ I think you want index $i$ or exponent $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether $s_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms, which means from $0$ to $n-1$, or the sum of the terms up to $n$, which is $n+1$ of them.  You are using the first definition.  The problem seems to be using the second.  The extra term is what changes the exponent on $r$.